# Export Java Object with complete object graph to csv

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot, export-to-csv, opencsv

I am currently working on a requirement, wherein i have to export a complete object graph to CSV like :

```
Entity Classes :
 1. Company : id, Name, List<Department> 
 2. Department : id, Name, List<Employee>
 3. Employee : id, Name, List <Skill>
 4. Skill : id, Name
 5. EmployeeSkills : emp_id, skill_id
```

and here if i extract an entity for Company, i have the complete object graph, which i want to export in below format :

```
company_id, company_name, Department_id, department_name, employee_id, employee_name , skills
```

here skills will be space separated list of skill names.

just to give a real example :

say below is the Table data

Company

---

```
 id, name     
 1, ABC Corp
```

Department

---

```
 id, name, company_id
 10, Technology, 1
 11, Sales, 1
```

Employee

---

```
 id, name, dept_id
 100, vivek, 10
 101, mark, 10
 102, pradeep, 11
```

Skills

---

```
  id, name
  1000, java
  1001, spring
  1002, sales
```

EmployeeSkills

---

```
  emp_id,skill_id
  100,1000
  100,1001
  101,1001
  102,1002
```

and this needs to be exported as :

```
company_id, company_name, Department_id, department_name, employee_id, employee_name , skill, skill
1, ABC Corp, 10, Technology, 100, vivek, java, spring
1, ABC Corp, 10, Technology, 101, mark, java,
1, ABC Corp, 11, Technology, 102, pradeep, sales,
```

- here list of Object Type, or Any Composed object is expanded into its data members
- and list of skills is expanded into multiple columns with same name i.e. skill
- if there were an entity with 3 skills, there will be 3 columns in csv with name as skill

Is there any csv library which can be used for such custom mapping of entire object graph

OR

would I need to create a DTO in the required format and export that using OpenCSV or any other library ? like :

CompanyCsvDto

---

company_id, company_name, Department_id, department_name, employee_id, employee_name , skills

Comment: You create POJOs for each of your entity and use a library like OpenCSV to serialize them to CSV. You got to try it to be more specific with the question

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla - added more details, it that explains it well now... :-)